# Multiple db contexts not creating full database

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dbcontext

I have 2 DbContext's, 1 for the `Identity` user management and another for the application. My `IdentityDbContext` looks like below:

```
public class IdentityDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public IdentityDbContext(DbContextOptions<IdentityDbContext> options)
    : base(options)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
}
```

And the `ApplicationDbContext` looks like this:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext
{
   public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
   : base(options)
   { }

   public DbSet<Email> Emails { get; set; }
}
```

My `Startup`:

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
 {
     services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<IdentityDbContext>()
        .AddUserManager<UserManager<ApplicationUser>>()
        .AddErrorDescriber<LocalizedIdentityErrorDescriber>()
        .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

      services
        .AddDbContext<IdentityDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("dotvvm")),ServiceLifetime.Transient)
        .AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("dotvvm")),ServiceLifetime.Transient);
  }
```

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, ApplicationDbContext dbContext, IdentityDbContext identityDbContext)
{
    dbContext.Database.EnsureCreated();
    identityDbContext.Database.EnsureCreated();
}
```

When I run the application, only the tables from the ApplicationDbContext are created whilst the tables in the IdentityDbContext aren't. However if I remove the ApplicationDbContext the IdentityDbContext tables are created and vice versa.

Have I configured multi db context's wrong? Or is there something I'm missing?

Comment: What happens when you run the migrations? I haven't tried this, but try `add-migration` `name` `Context _context` for both. Then `update-database`.

Comment: The connections string for both databases are the same.  They should be different in the Startup.

Comment: @jdweng Having multiple DB contexts doesn’t necessarily mean you have to have multiple DB’s

Comment: @bolkay Thank you very much! I didn't think of that :)